# Writing all possible combinations of a characters in a string to a file using Python

Tags: python, file, combinations, cartesian-product

I have a string s="abcde". I want to generate all possible permutations and write their in txt file.
OUT File.txt

a
b
c
d
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
ba
bb
bc
bd
be
ca
cb
cc
cd
ce
da
db
dc
dd
de
ea
eb
ec
ed
ee
...
...
eeeda
eeedb
eeedc
eeedd
eeede
eeeea
eeeeb
eeeec
eeeed
eeeee

I used the itertools but it always start with aaaaa.

Comment: Share your code please. Looks like you just need to generate the 'permutations' of length 1, then 2, then 3 etc... up to the length you want, which can be done easily with a `for` loop.

Comment: This is not permutations! show us your code and expected output vs. real output

Answer (score -1):

itertools.permutations takes 2 arguments, the iterable and length of the permutations. If you do not specify the second agrument, it defaults to len(iterable). To get all lengths, you need to print permutations for each length:

```
import itertools
s = "abcde"
for i in range(len(s)):
    for permutation in (itertools.permutations(s, i+1)):
        print ("".join(permutation))
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: Yep, indeed permutations take two elements. I was writing in a hurry and forgot that :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import itertools

s="abcde"

def upto_n(s,n):

    out = []

    for i in range(1,n+1,1):

        out += list(itertools.combinations(s, i))

    return out

print upto_n(s,2)
print upto_n(s,3)
```

**OutPut**

```
 [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('d', 'e')]

 [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('d', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'd', 'e'), ('c', 'd', 'e')]
```

Comment: This is also incorrect per OP's output. They want repeating characters too.